# 404 not found when using beyondcode

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am trying to use the beyondcode. But now I am getting this error in my console. Please help me how can I solve this.

```
# POST http://localhost:5173/broadcasting/auth 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: We need more info, we can't do anything with what you sared

Comment: You can check if the `BroadcastProvider` is uncommented in the `config/app.php`